# MapServer WMS: Not all features show, depending on how I zoom and pan

Tags: qgis, wms, mapserver

Here is how QGIS shows an irrigation network, received by MapServer via WMS and superimposed on OpenStreetMap:

[image]

Here is the same thing, but slightly panned to the right:

[image]

Several items are obviously missing. In fact there are items missing in the top picture as well. Different items become visible as I zoom and pan differently.

[This link](https://poros.irmasys.com/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/opt/aira-poros/aira-poros/mapserver/extralayers.map&service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=irrigation-network&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&width=256&height=256&srs=EPSG%3A3857&bbox=2329800.622132173,4813698.29328726,2331023.6145847356,4814921.285739826) provides this tile (which I subsequently show on leaflet):

[image]

This is how QGIS shows that area if I manage to zoom and pan in a way that (I think) all information is shown:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I don't see anything in the MapServer logs. MapServer version is 7.6.2 (prepackaged for Debian).

### Appendix

Here is parts of the map file:

```
MAP
    NAME "aira-poros"
    STATUS ON
    SIZE 9040 7731
    EXTENT 103986.57 3850796.18 1007945.14 4623933.00
    UNITS meters
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:2100"
    END
    CONFIG MS_ERRORFILE "/var/log/mapserver/extralayers.log"

    # [Omitting some OUTPUTFORMAT sections]

    WEB
        IMAGEPATH "/var/cache/mapserver/"
        IMAGEURL "/mapserver_tmp/"
        METADATA
            "wms_title" "Aira Poros"
            "wms_onlineresource" "https://poros.irmasys.com/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/opt/aira-poros/aira-poros/mapserver/extralayers.map&"
            "wms_srs" "EPSG:4326 EPSG:2100 EPSG:3857"
            "wms_enable_request" "*"
            "wms_feature_info_mime_type" "text/html"

            "wfs_title" "Aira Poros"
            "wfs_onlineresource" "https://poros.irmasys.com/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/opt/aira-poros/aira-poros/mapserver/extralayers.map&"
            "wfs_srs" "EPSG:2100 EPSG:4326 EPSG:3857"
            "wfs_enable_request" "*"
        END
    END

    LAYER
        NAME "irrigation-network" 
        TYPE LINE
        CONNECTIONTYPE OGR
        CONNECTION "irrigation-network.gml"
        METADATA
            "wms_title" "Irrigation network"
            "wfs_title" "Irrigation network"
            "gml_include_items" "all"
            "gml_featureid" "id"
        END
        STATUS ON
        PROJECTION
            "init=epsg:2100"
        END
        CLASSITEM 'category'
        CLASS
            EXPRESSION '1'
            STYLE
                COLOR 0 0 255
                OPACITY 50
                WIDTH 6
            END
            LABEL
                COLOR 0 0 255
                ANGLE FOLLOW
                OFFSET 5 99
                MAXSCALEDENOM 10000
                TEXT "[irri_code]"
            END
            LABEL
                COLOR 0 0 255
                ANGLE FOLLOW
                OFFSET -8 99
                MAXSCALEDENOM 10000
                EXPRESSION (NOT('[Diameter]' = ''))
                TEXT "D=[Diameter] mm"
            END
        END

        # [Omitting three more classes]
    END

    # [Omitting four more layers]
END
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with the WMS link?

Comment: Could you add the network information from QGIS (hit F12)?

Comment: @swiss_knight You mean the requests? I'm not certain what exactly to copy. I think it might be faster for you to see them yourself than to explain to me what you want. The base URL is https://poros.irmasys.com/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/opt/aira-poros/aira-poros/mapserver/extralayers.map; there are five layers, and the one in question is the "Irrigation network" (although all layers have the problem).

Comment: @DannaC17 The base URL is https://poros.irmasys.com/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/opt/aira-poros/aira-poros/mapserver/extralayers.map. There's also a link with a specific request in the question immediately above the third image.

Comment: Why request using EPSG:3857 as per your 'tile' example , when the canvas is EPSG:4326 and the service supports EPSG:4326.

Comment: @nmtoken Does this make any difference? I merely copied the URL of the request Leaflet is making.

Comment: Can you share your map file, or at least the metadata sections and the labelling rules the latter appears to be scale dependent, if so how is that calculated

Comment: As an aside, if you want transparent images Leaflet should (according to the specification) send  `TRUE` not `true`; the values are case sensitive and default is FALSE

Comment: If I use EPSG:2100 for the QGIS canvas, and request the WMS as EPSG:2100, with OpenStreetMap backdrop, and zoom/pan around at scale 1:4538, I cannot replicate your issue

Comment: @AntonisChristofides - I'd recommend converting your data to a shapefile and see if the issue is resolved. When data appears/disappears like this often an extent or spatial index is incorrect or corrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nmtoken had suspected (see his answer), the problem occurred when MapServer was reprojecting the data from EPSG:2100 (Greek grid—the CRS of the data files) to EPSG:3857.

The problem disappeared when I upgraded MapServer from 7.6.2 to 8.0.0. I didn't want to compile MapServer and I used a version from Debian bullseye backports, which only has 8.0.0, so I don't know if the problem exists in 7.6.4.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like either you have an error in your data, or QGIS/MapServer is having problems reprojecting between EPSG:3857 (WMS requests) and EPSG:2100 (WFS request and native format).  You can see looking at them together in QGIS using EPSG:2100.

[image: WMS/WFS data mismatch]

It looks like in the layer metadata (map file) you currently have

```
"WMS_SRS" "EPSG:2100"
```

perhaps change this to:

```
"OWS_SRS" "EPSG:2100 EPSG:3857 EPSG:4326"
```

Then QGIS will allow you to select say EPSG:2100 for both the WMS/WFS.

Comment: I added the map file to the question. I think that the problem you see here is because you've chosen SRS 2700 when you actually meant 2100. I can reproduce what you're seeing with 2700, but not with 2100, 4326 or 3857.

Comment: oops, you're right that I incorrectly chose 2700, but QGIS should do reprojection on the fly, so the data should align even if QGIS has to do the reprojection from 2100 to 2700.